# Сделать JOIN с подстановкой данных по времени

Tags: postgresql, join

Есть две таблицы `orders` и `prices`

#### Orders

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (
    count        integer                  not null,
    created_at   timestamp with time zone not null,
    product_id   integer                  not null
);
```

#### Prices

```sql
CREATE TABLE prices (
    retail     integer                  not null,
    discount   integer                  not null,
    created_at timestamp with time zone not null,
    product_id integer                  not null
);
```

Необходимо сделать выборку количества заказов по определенному товару `product_id` и в определенный период времени, но еще сделать JOIN с таблицей цен `prices` так, чтобы цены соответствовали по времени этих заказов.

Пример данных:

***orders***

| count | created_at | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-10 10:00:00 | 100 |
| 3 | 2023-01-10 12:00:00 | 100 |
| 2 | 2023-01-10 14:00:00 | 100 |
| 4 | 2023-01-10 16:00:00 | 100 |
| 1 | 2023-01-10 18:00:00 | 100 |

***prices***

| retail | discount | created_at | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1050 | 5 | 2023-01-10 8:00:00 | 100 |
| 990 | 10 | 2023-01-10 11:00:00 | 100 |
| 1100 | 0 | 2023-01-10 13:00:00 | 100 |
| 1200 | 15 | 2023-01-10 14:35:00 | 100 |
| 990 | 3 | 2023-01-10 17:40:00 | 100 |

В результате хочу получить список заказов с ценой:

| count | retail | discount | created_at | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1050 | 5 | 2023-01-10 10:00:00 | 100 |
| 3 | 990 | 10 | 2023-01-10 12:00:00 | 100 |
| 2 | 1100 | 0 | 2023-01-10 14:00:00 | 100 |
| 4 | 1200 | 15 | 2023-01-10 16:00:00 | 100 |
| 1 | 990 | 3 | 2023-01-10 18:00:00 | 100 |

Пытаюсь подобрать правильное условие для JOIN, но пока неудачно. Наверное JOIN тут и не нужен.
Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Ваша схема навязывает пользователю схему продаж, так как ваш заказ может содержать только один вид товара отрицая понятие корзины, тем самым вы превращаете ваш продукт в "Твистер" для потребителя. Использование прайса для определения цены по завершенным заказам нарушает принцип единственной ответственности и лишает гибкости необходимой для любых форм дисконта. Вам бы над схемой еще подумать...

Comment: Логичнее делать запрос из таблицы `prices` и уже к ней делать join таблицы `orders`. Join тут нужен, так как вам нужны данные из двух таблиц.

Comment: *Пример данных* Дайте его в виде INSERT INTO. И добавьте требуемый результат запроса для именно этих данных с подробным пояснением, хотя бы по паре строк.

Answer (score 0):

Чисто из описания:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM orders
JOIN LATERAL ( 
    SELECT *
    FROM prices
    WHERE orders.product_id = prices.product_id
      AND orders.created_at >= prices.created_at
    ORDER BY prices.created_at DESC LIMIT 1 ) price ON 1=1
```

Ну а с умножениями и прочей арифметикой сам разберёшься...